# Two ways to authenticate: CAS + SpringSecurity

Tags: java, spring, authentication, double, cas

my thought is to create a website where you can authenticate in two different ways: from a typical login (SpringSecurity) and from a CAS server. 
A user reaching any protected page should be redirected to /login page, where Username and Password are needed to proceed further. Then we have a choice: clicking on "Login" button will authenticate the user ONLY for this site; otherwise clicking on "Login with CAS" will redirect the User on the Login of the CAS-server (or maybe, better: directly submit Username and Password to the CAS server) and then redirected to the web application.

Either from local or CAS, a user successfully logged in must have access to the site. How can I do this? For now, I only got the local authentication - and it's working.

**spring-security.xml**

```
 <http auto-config="true">        
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" /> 
    <intercept-url pattern="/static/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/srv/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <...>
    </http>

 <form-login login-page='/login'
                default-target-url="/home"
                authentication-success-handler-ref="authSuccessHandler"
                authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login" /> 
    <session-management invalid-session-url="/login">
      <concurrency-control expired-url="/login" />
    </session-management>       
</http>

<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider ref="authProvider"/>
</authentication-manager>
```

I'm not using SpringBoot; i got SpringSecurity 4.0.3 and Spring Framework 4.3.7

Comment: Can you explain why do you need two authentication methods? In general, by using cas you can authenticate a user only for a target service.

Comment: Well, i'm just programming under instructions my boss gave me, but I understood that CAS Server we're connecting to is unstable and we want a backup-service to authenticate users.